# Python-Requests timeout incompatibility

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm about ready to throw in the towel and do everything with cURL.

Using python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 and python-requests 2.11.1 I can't send any requests. **Whether I leave the timeout out or specify it as an int, a float, or a tuple, I get "ValueError('Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=70, read=70, total=None), but it must be an int or a float').**

I've read in similar questions that it could be an issue with older distributions of python or requests, but I have up to date versions of both. I've also tried downgrading Requests to a previous version (2.9.1), but the error remained. Is the requests library just broken locally? Should I just do this in urllib?

```
data = {
    'description': 'customer for account: ' + str(account_id),
    'email': email,
    'source': token
}

customer = requests.post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers', data=data, auth=('sk_test_mykey', ''), timeout=70)
```

Comment: This was a problem on older versions but it should be fixed by now. Is your python interpreter grabbing the right module? Can you run ``python -c 'import requests; print(requests.__version__)'``?

Comment: I get a syntax error with that specific command, but if I just enter the interpreter and print the requests.__version__ it says 2.11.1, the version I installed with pip.